# Differences between cast arraylist and cast array in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, casting

As the Jon's answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358546/casting-between-arraylists-in-java) has said, if compiler allows this cast (shown below), to add some other objects later can be a bad thing for program.

```
    ArrayList<String> temList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Object> obList = (ArrayList<Object>)temList;//compile error
    //obList.add(1); --bad
```

But what confuses me is why in the same situation, array has the different behaviours.

```
    String[] strings = new String[10];
    Object[] temp = (Object[])strings;//nothing happens
```

So could anyone explain what is the **difference** here and why java make such **design**? Thanks.

**Edit:** one similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not 100% Objects, they are mundane objects. But `ArrayList` a 100% object.

If you try to assign an Integer to the temp array it will throw an [`ArrayStoreException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html).

So casting arrays is fine.

But Casting `ArrayList` to a Super Object where the Underlying ArrayList implementation can only hold a String (Sub Class) will cause problems during the Runtime.

Thanks to Generics the compiler can identify this before it happens and can show a compiler error. This is a good design if not the program will fail during runtime.

Prior to Java 1.5 Generics

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add(1);
list.add("One");
list.add(100l);
```

Was legal the coders had to do a lot of `instanceof` checks. Where they failed to check the program crashed during runtime.

Comment: Semi-unrelated question, why is it that people attribute Javascript's ability to store different kind of objects in an array a positive? It basically functions as an Object[] in Java, just without the casting. I believe it to be a coding hazard.

Comment: @shazin Sorry, but what is the mundane object mean? Any example or references? And why array doesn't make this kind of cast a compiler error. Thanks.

Comment: @Tony it means it is not a 100% object because it doesn't have functions on anything but it has a fields like 'length'. It is more than a premitive variable but less than a fully fledged object.

Comment: @shazin Um, arrays extend `Object`. Therefore, they are "fully fledged objects". No question about it.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays were designed to allow covariant assignments if an array's component type is assignable to the assigned array's component type. Type checks are rather done at runtime by the JVM where an [`ArrayStoreException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html) is thrown in case a value is attempted to be stored in an incompatible array. Used right, this allowed to express covariant types for array's what is often handy.

However, this language feature can lead to diffuse runtime exceptions what Sun did not want to repeat for generic type assignments which were introduced with Java 5. Instead, Sun wanted to uncover such invalid use at compile time. This seemed especially important as generics introduced a more complex type system component than array types such that runtime errors similar to the `ArrayStoreException` would surely have become more common if Sun had decided differently. Instead, for generics the issues of co- and contravariance were addressed by wildcards which allow to uncover type errors at compile time instead of runtime.